# Adding multiple values for a key in a dictionary for Python

Tags: python, json

Hello I am trying to retrieve multiple indcode using the below code. However I get an error saying "cannot specify for field more than once" Can you anyone please assist?

```
URL = "https://data.colorado.gov/resource/cjkq-q9ih.json"
D = dict()
D["area"] = 57
D["indcode"] = 10,23,81

document = requests.get(URL, D)
print(document.request.url)
```

Error message received.

{
"error" : true,
"message" : "cannot specify a field more than once"
}

[screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I05Wf.png)

```
document = requests.get(URL, D)
print(document.request.url)
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75392902/edit) your question and add the complete error message.

Comment: Can u upload error? Running the ```D``` code works?

Comment: Your URL is a complete JSON document.  It doesn't take parameters.  Just download the document and search the list of dictionaries it returns for the entries you want.  FYI, I see "area=57" entries but no "indcode" of 10, 23 or 81.

Comment: I have to use a python code that will retrieve for multiple indcode

Comment: It appears the api does not support requesting multiple values for indcode.  Or, perhaps it does, but you're doing it the wrong way.  In any case, this is not really a programming question; it is a question of the particular interface for that api.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Actually, it appears that it does take parameters.  It seems odd, but I tried a request for `cjkq-q9ih.json?indcode=622`, and I received a response of only items with that indcode value.

Answer (score 0):

Getting data with multiple indcode is impossible at that URL until web developers provide that feature. You can try with another way.

If you want to retrieve multiple `indcode`, just try to iterate all data in one request from https://data.colorado.gov/resource/cjkq-q9ih.json?area=57. Try this :

```
import requests
URL = "https://data.colorado.gov/resource/cjkq-q9ih.json"
D = dict()
D["area"] = 57
# D["indcode"] = 10,23,81
indcode = [10,23,81]

document = requests.get(URL, D)
data = document.json()
filteredData = list(filter(lambda p: int(p['indcode']) in indcode, data))
print(filteredData)
```